# Solutions for using columnar store with compression but allowing recent rows to be updated - Greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I'm looking for specific examples of where someone has solved the following problem in Greenplum (or in another MPP db):

I have large fact tables that I would like to store in columnar orientation and compress (in Greenplum this would specifically be level 5 zlib compression).

However, each new row has a short time period where it can be updated before it becomes "static" - for example a value is allowed to change until some flag is raised. In Greenplum to use compression I need to use "append only" table types meaning the row cannot be directly updated safely.

So, in my inexperienced head, I believe an approach to this could be to have two tables - one holding the rows while they are allowed to be updated which can use standard HEAP storage and has no compression, and one holding only those that have become "static" (the vast majority) which is in columnar orientation and is compressed.

Clearly there are mechanics involved that make life more complex (unioning the two if I want to look at *everything*, triggering the deletion from one table and insertion into the other when the row becomes static, etc etc) so I'd really appreciate hearing about a real life solution to this problem.

Thanks

Andy.

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum 4.3.x allows you to update column-oriented tables, you should use this version

In general, you can have partitioned table, partition by the "updatable" flag (one partition should be AO CO, one heap). This way your select queries won't be affected, but moving data from one partition to another would require removing the data from the heap partition and inserting it into column-oriented partition (not that complex to implement though)